# Formar pares de números en un bucle con Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

```
const numbersArray = [8, 2, 6, 8, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 9, 0, 5, 3, 7, 8, 8, 5, 9, 1, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
  const number = numbersArray[i];
  for (let w; w < i; w++) {
    // Aqui se forman los pares
  }
}
```

Tengo un array `numbersArray` que contiene 20 números enteros entre 0 y 9, algunos están repetidos. Por otro lado tambien tengo un bucle `for` donde `number` va recorriendo a `numbersArray`. Lo que busco hacer en el bucle es formar pares de números iguales sin par, por ejemplo:

Si `number` es igual a `5` y anteriormente ya salio un número `5` y no tiene par, imprime en consola el número del par y su posición en el array `numbersArray` de cada uno.

Al final deberia haber:

- Dos pares de `8`.
- Un par de `0` y un `0` sin par.
- Un par de `7`.
- Dos pares de `5`.
- Un par de `9`.

**Un número con par no puede formar parte de otro par.*

Pense que para diferenciar los números con par de los que no tienen par, podria sumarles `.1`, pero es necesario que sigan siendo del tipo enteros, asi que no se como diferenciarlos.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente contar los números... es decir... por ejemplo para el numero 8, recorres todo el array contando los 8... al final te da como resultado que hay 4.. lo que significa 2 pares... si te da 0 es que ese numero no existe, si te da 1 es que solo hay un numero y no tiene par, si te da 2 es que hay un par, si te da 3 es que hay un par y uno sin par, si te da 4 es 2 pares, si te da 5 es dos pares y uno que no tiene par... y así sucesivamente. De hecho se podría hacer mejor con `map` o con un `reduce`, en vez de con dos ciclos anidados.

Comment: Sebastián, hola, podrías decirme si te fue util la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero creamos un nuevo arreglo llamado **unico** que contendrá todos los elementos del arreglo original(**numbersArray**), pero no contendrá elementos duplicados, es decir si en el arreglo original el 8 aparece 3 veces aquí solamente aparecerá una vez. Para esto se usa el **método filter**.

```
 let unicos = numbersArray.filter((item, index)=>{
  return numbersArray.indexOf(item) === index;
 })

var contador = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < unicos.length; i++)
{
   contador = 0;

   for(var j = 0; j < numbersArray.length; j++)
   {
      if(unicos[i] === numbersArray[j])
      {
         contador++;
      }
   }

   var pares = (Math.trunc(contador / 2));

   if(contador == 1)
   {
      console.log(unicos[i] + ": sin par");
   }
   else if(contador % 2 == 0)       
   {
      console.log(unicos[i] + ": " + pares + " par(es)");
   }
   else
   {
      console.log(unicos[i] + ": " + pares + " par(es)");
      console.log(unicos[i] + ": sin par");
   }
}
```

Después de crear el **arreglo** **unico** se procederá entonces a saber la cantidad de veces que se repite cada elemento de este **arreglo** **unico** en el arreglo original **numbersArray**.

Para esto se hacen dos **ciclos for anidados**, el primero que recorra todos los elementos del **arreglo unico** y el segundo que recorra todos los elementos del **arreglo numbersArray**, y entonces por cada elemento del **arreglo unico** se contaría cuantas veces aparece este elemento en el arreglo original. Después de efectuarse este conteo se pregunta si el mismo es **1**, de ser **1** quiere decir que ese elemento no tiene par, por lo tanto se imprime **"sin par"**, se pregunta si la **variable contador** es un número par de serlo se divide entre **2**, y esta división sería entonces la cantidad de pares que tiene ese elemento, de ser impar la división se divide igualmente el contador entre 2 y se imprimiría esa cantidad de pares, pero en este caso como contador es impar quiere decir que hay un elemento que se queda sin par, por tanto se imprimiría además que ese elemento además de los pares que tiene, se queda uno sin par.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio mucho!